# Photosynthesis: Can light directly excite the reaction center instead of going through the antenna complex?

Tags: photosynthesis

The reaction centers that I am interested in are P680(photosystem II) and P700 (photosystem I)

Here is what I think:

If pigments such as chlorophyll a and b capture light in the antenna complex, and

if the reaction center contains chlorophyll a,

then the reaction center should be able to directly capture photons and transfer their electron to an electron acceptor.

Or do reaction centers use energy from both the sun and antenna complex?

Also, a side question, I thought chlorophyll a were also efficient at absorbing light in the 400nm to 400nm range, but then why are reaction centers called based on their absorption of 680nm and 700nm light?

Thanks!